# C++, error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope in a for loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a code that pop_back()-s numbers[i] into either one of these vectors: oddnumbers and evennumbers
but unfortunately I got ' 'i' was not declared in this scope'
the code is following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers = {2,4,3,6,1,9};
    std::vector<int> evennumbers;
    std::vector<int> oddnumbers;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers[6]; i++) {
        if (numbers[i]%2 == 0) {
            evennumbers.pop_back(numbers[i]);
        }
        else if (numbers[i]%2 != 0) {
            oddnumbers.pop_back(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please keep an eye on proper indentation (as I fixed for you), code gets much more readable this way.

Comment: Side note: `numbers[6]` is *not* in valid range of the vector as with 6 values entered, only indices from 0 to 5 are valid. Did you want to iterate over the elements in the vector? Then you should have selected `numbers.size()` as upper limit.

Comment: There are several issues with your code, if you would like to learn from:
1. C++ indices start from 0, therefore, numbers[6] is off-by-one and a critical error, furthermore,
2. you attempted to use the last element of "numbers" as the max. index, which is a logical error (you want the actual size of the vec, not whatever happens to be stored as last element).
3. To avoid this, use range-based for
4. A common simplification which you should get used to, if you only have two possibilities "if (...) else ...", simply omit specifiying the exact inverse cond. in the else path (implicit).

Comment: Further, you want push_back or emplace_back, not pop_back.
This is so wrong, and new account first time poster, I'm starting to feel like I'm being trolled :o)

Comment: @Aconcagua: It seems like it's purposefully made as terrible as possible for all our amusement :-)

Comment: @smoothware You are too strict. She/he is probably a total beginner and yet lacks quite a lot of understanding...

Comment: @Aconcagua, well, that's ok to a certain extent, the IT community expects at least the very bare minimum of self-initiative, it only takes literally 10 seconds to see how to add a number to vector<int>, and that pop_back is not even close to being correct:
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/
Learn to read the C++ docs on standard library, it will help a ton.

Comment: @smoothware Just as you say: *Learn to read* – that's what she/he still needs to accomplish... It is so easy for experienced coders like us to forget about all the pitfalls we once stumbled over ourselves. So we might just wait and see how she/he develops further on.

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler says, there is no declaration of `i`.

Replace

```
for (i = 0; i < numbers[6]; i++) {
```

by

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers[6]; i++) {
```

Comment: No offense, but I don't think this is a good answer, because it ignores many of the obvious major mistakes in that piece of code, and what you show may compile, but is still wrong.